# How do the various "..Instances" pragma's work together, and is there a way around my current problem?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

Consider the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
class X a
class Y a
instance Y Bool
instance (Y a) => X a
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} X Int

f :: (X a) => a -> a
f x = x
```

These LANGUAGE pragma's are needed to write the above instances.

Now, say we want to write a function g:

```
g :: (Y a) => a -> a
g = f
```

Without IncoherentInstances or adding {-# INCOHERENT #-} to one of the instances, this doesn't typecheck.
But when we do add this, and ask ghci

```
ghci> :t f
f :: Y a => a -> a
```

Suddenly the type of 'f' changed?

With this small example, programs still typecheck when I give f an Int (indicating that the above would be merely a 'visual bug', but in a bigger example the same does not typecheck, giving me an error like:

```
Could not deduce (Y a) arising from a use of 'f
(...)
from the context: (..., X a, ...)
```

This also happens when we say

```
h = f
```

and try to call h with an Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:type f` does not report the type of the defined entity `f`. It reports the type of the expression `f`. GHC tries really hard to stamp polymorphism out of expressions. In particular, using `f` in an expression triggers simplification of the `X a` constraint (as does using any definition with a constraint). Without `IncoherentInstances`, GHC refrains from using `instance Y a => X a`, because there is another instance that overlaps it, so GHC needs to wait to see which one it should use. This ensures coherence; the *only* `X Int` instance that is ever used is the explicitly "specialized" one. With `IncoherentInstances`, you say that you don't care about coherence, so GHC goes ahead and simplifies `X a` to `Y a` using the polymorphic instance whenever `f` appears in an expression. The weird behavior you see where sometimes GHC is OK with using `X Int` and sometimes complains that there is no `Y Int` is a result of GHC making different internal decisions about when it wants to simplify constraints (you did ask for *incoherence*!). The command for seeing the type of a *definition* is `:type +v`. `:type +v f` should show the type of `f` "as declared". Hopefully, you can also see that `IncoherentInstances` is a bad idea. Don't use it.

Comment: What is the proper way to make a typeclass X which has instances for every type that Y has an instance for, as well as an extra instance for, say, Int (if there is not and cannot be an instance of Y Int)? Is the only real way, to add the constraint (X a) to the definition of Y? What if Y is out of your control, or you don't want to manually write all the instances for X?

Comment: What you've written is the best you can do. You just can't write `g`.

Comment: What's the point of these instances if I can't use a Y whenever I need an X? This situation feels very lacking, given how simple the problem at hand should be..

Comment: But you cannot use a `Y a` when you need an `X a` if `a` is `Int`. I suspect that you just *don't need* `g`. In any context where `a` is *known* not to be `Int`, `f`'s constraint will simplify anyway. Or maybe you should just write `g :: Y a => a -> a` in the first place and make `f` a class method of `X`, with `f = g` in one instance and `f = _whatever` in the other.

Comment: Thank you for the input! In my case, "f" is a GADT constructor so I can't put it inside of the typeclass definition. The reason I made X, is because I want to express that the GADT can contain types that either have an instance for Y, or are this other type.

Comment: But you *can* put it in the class (ish): `data MyGADT a = Y a => WithY a | (a ~ Int) => IsInt a; class X a where { fromX :: a -> MyGADT y }; instance Y a => X a where { fromX = HasY }; instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} X Int where fromX = IsInt`. You even get fun things like `withX :: MyGADT a -> (X a => r) -> r`